# CakePHP filtering data with conditions on its related data

Tags: cakephp

If I have models like:

```
User hasMany house hasMany belongings
```

and I want to select all Users and the related models, but only if the user has one or more belongings--how would I set that condition? Thanks!!

Comment: Do you mean return only users who have houses with belongings in them?

Answer (score 0):

use counterCache, then you can set the condition in pagination: 'belonging_count >'=> 0